# Is there a byte limit on row size for normal or indexed views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Understanding there is a 8,060 byte limit on row size for tables when columns are defined ( per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server ), does the same apply to *normal or indexed views* in SQL Server?

Comment: Normal views, indexed views or both?

Comment: The limit is for *key values* -- when a key exceeds this size, it can't be stored in an index (or used in a sort operation even when not indexed). A table row can be as broad as you like, per the remark right next to it: "SQL Server supports row-overflow storage which enables variable length columns to be pushed off-row." So if your view is indexed, the index is subject to this limit, but nothing else is.

Comment: Edited question to ask about both normal and indexed views

Answer (score 1):

Normal Views  just encapsulate query ,so talking about row level sizes for views is not valid

with Indexed views ,data is persisted to disk as seperate copy,view changes into indexed view ,only when you create a clustered index on the view.

However you can't choose  wide key with more than 900  in versions earlier than 2016 sp1.So talking about row limit size for indexed view is also not valid